# How do I use Javascript to remove text before and including the last instance of a character in multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, substring, getelementsbytagname, lastindexof

I'm new to Javascript, so I'm doing my best to learn, but I'm stuck on how this works. I have html that looks similar to this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
     <p>string/string/Red</p>
     <p>string/string/Green</p>
     <p>string/string/Blue</p>
</div>
```

I want to use Javascript to remove all the text before and including the last instance of "/" like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
     <p>Red</p>
     <p>Green</p>
     <p>Blue</p>
</div>
```

From the examples I've seen, I believe I need to use substring() and lastIndexOf() in some way, but admittedly I don't know enough about Javascript to understand how it's supposed to work. This is the code I'm working with, but I don't know how to incorporate substring() and lastIndexOf() to get what I want:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var y = x.getElementsByTagName("P");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
     y[i].innerHTML = // WHAT GOES HERE?;
}
```

Can anyone help a newbie out?

Comment: You would wanna accept the answer which works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve it using split and pop
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

```
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
     y[i].innerHTML = y[i].innerHTML.split('/').pop()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each node, split the text into an array and take the last item:

```js
var ps = document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv p'), i;
for (i = 0; i < ps.length; ++i) {
   ps[i].textContent = ps[i].textContent.split("/").pop();
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
     <p>string/string/Red</p>
     <p>string/string/Green</p>
     <p>string/string/Blue</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with regex:

```
x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace(/^.*\//, '');
```

Comment: Split solution would be most probably faster tho :)